# If $a_n=\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\dots+\frac{1}{n!}$, show that $2\le \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n\le 3$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If $ a_n=\cfrac{1}{0!}+\cfrac{1}{1!}+\cfrac{1}{2!}+\dots+\cfrac{1}{n!}$, show that $2\le \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n\le 3$.

Comment: What are the assumptions you can use? What are the steps you have taken?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I can prove that it is monotonic increasing function, but can't prove that it is bounded.

Comment: This is not true. You haven't included the term $\frac1{0!}$ at the beginning, so $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n \approx 1.72$, not $2.72$.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks, I think the question is misprinted.

Comment: Please see: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/471959

Comment: You should include some attempts, especially since this is one of the most classical exercises in Calculus. Proving the sharper $\frac{19}{7}<e<\frac{20}{7}$ through elementary techniques is more challenging.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'll try proving this.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}&=2+\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k!}\\
&\leq 2+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k(k-1)}\\
&=\ldots\\
&=2+\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k-1}-\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k}\\
&=2+1 - \text{?}\\
\end{align}

I deliberately left gaps for you to fill in.

Comment: Kevin.Very nice!

Comment: $?=\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @Vincent Sure is yes. Be careful about monotinicity and upper limits, what can you say here?

Comment: @Kevin that it is monotonically increasing and has upper limit, so it converges?

Comment: @Vincent Yes, job done!

Answer (score 2):

An option:

$2 \lt a_n =$

$1+1+1/2!+1/3! + 1/n! \lt $

$(2) +(1/2 +1/2^2+...+1/2^n) \lt$

$(1+1) + (1/2+1/2^2+1/2^3.....)$.

The sum in the second parenthesis above is the infinite geometric series, first term $1/2$, constant ratio $1/2.$

What is it's sum?

Comment: $2+\cfrac{1}{2}\biggl(\cfrac{1}{1-\cfrac{1}{2}}\biggr) = 3$

Answer (score 1):

First let's change the question a little:

Set $b_n=a_{n+4}$ so we get $2\le \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\le 3$ to be $2\le \overbrace{a_0+a_1}^2+a_2+a_3+\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n\le 3\iff 0\le a_2+a_3+\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n\le 1$

---

Now we notice that for all $n>3$ we have $\frac1{2^n}>\frac1{n!}$, so we have$$0\le a_2+a_3+\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n< a_2+a_3+\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{2^4}+\frac1{2^4}+\cdots+\frac1{2^n}\right)$$ I'll leave the proof that the last part(the geometric series) is equal to $\frac18$. From this we get$$0\le a_2+a_3+\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n< a_2+a_3+\frac18=\frac{19}{24}<1$$Hence $2\le \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n< 3$ we can change the $<$ to $\le$ without loosing anything to get $2\le \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\le 3$

Comment: This was an interesting solution.